# Why do I suddenly have 2 onedrive folders, and how can I fix it?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, onedrive

I dont recall doing anything to cause this, but suddenly my system (windows 8.1 enterprise) has 2 onedrive folders. What caused this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are the paths for each folder?

Comment: Theyre both in the root of 2 partitions on 1 external drive

Comment: They contain the same files? Windows like to move things to the partition with the largest free space sometimes.  Its not a typical configuration for a profile directory to be on a external drive though.

Comment: This happened to me too. Additionally, after updating today, when I logged in Windows first complained that it couldn't find my OneDrive folder (even though it was there) and had me "set it up" again. Then it complained that the OneDrive folder existed already and asked me to merge my files. Now I have two folders called C:\Users\{User}\OneDrive with different contents...